# Generate multiple PDFs from CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, msbi

I have a requirement to generate multiple pdfs from csv files. Need to generate a pdf for each customer

There are two CSV files

First file contains list of customers with basic information like address, id, etc.
Second file contains all customers transactions like debits, credits.

Please suggest how to create PDFs from CSV files

Comment: try using `iTextSharp`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use iTextSharp. 
I suppose this library is used for manual pdf files creation. So you can use it for any format that you can read and csv as well.

This library is distributed under paid license and open-source AGPL license.

Sourceforge:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Official Site:
http://itextpdf.com/